# Are user journey maps for multiple personas possible?

Tags: personas, process, journey-map

I'm creating a user journey map for a digital solution that will be used by engineers and their supervisors to complete repair tasks.

In this solution an engineer will submit a request and the supervisor will approve the request from their approval dashboard. Once approved the engineer will get a notification and he can start on the repair task.

My question is how can we show this process on a user journey map. I've seen journey maps for commercial products with the journey of a single user in them. Is it possible to maps out a journey with multiple stakeholders on a user journey map? Would appreciate any examples. Also if this is not the right way to visualize the possess, please do suggest alternative types of maps/charts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What might help you is a service blueprint to show touchpoints between different users, systems, support processes etc.

[image]